# Construct custom for loop

Tags: scala, for-loop

The goal is to write a function that generate Gray codes for a certain value.

Currently I have this :

```
def gray(i: Int): List[String] = {
    if(i == 0) List("")
    else {
      val l = gray(i - 1)
      (l map {"0" + _}) ::: (l map{"1" + _})
    }
}
```

Output for `gray(3)` : `List(000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111)`

Then I have tried to construct this `List` with a for loop. Imagine that :

for `n = 2`, I will have :

```
def gray(i: Int): List[String] = {
    (for{a <- 0 to 1
         b <- 0 to 1} yield a+""+b).toList 
}
```

for `n = 3`, I will have :

```
def gray(i: Int): List[String] = {
    (for{a <- 0 to 1
         b <- 0 to 1
         c <- 0 to 1} yield a+""+b+""+c).toList 
  }
```

Obviously this doesn't take in account `i`, so I was wondering if we can build such a function which construct a custom for loop expression using `i`.

By construct I mean :

if `i == 2`, create `2` variables for the loop and yield them, if `i == 3` then create `3` and yield them, etc.

Is is possible ? (I'm a beginner in Scala)

Comment: "The one-bit Gray code is G1 = (0, 1). " your base case is wrong?

Comment: @StefanKunze Why ? If you have one bit available I will get `List(0,1)` because `l map {"0" + _}) ::: (l map{"1" + _}` will return `List("0") ::: List("1")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are not able to do so is because the `for expression` has to be specified at compile time, where as the `i` is only available at runtime. One option to do so would be to use macros which generate the required `for expression` but even in that case you will have to call that macro by passing a constant integer (rather a int variable which only resolves at runtime)

Comment: Since I begin Scala I suppose I shouldn't worry about that and go for the first option ?

Answer (score 5):

```
def gray(n: Integer): List[List[Char]] = {
    if (n == 0) List(List()) else
      for {
        c : List[Char] <- gray(n - 1)
        i : Char <- List('0', '1')
      } yield i :: c
  }                  //> gray: (n: Integer)List[List[Char]]

val of0 = gray(0)    //> of0  : List[List[Char]] = List(List())
val of1 = gray(1)    //> of1  : List[List[Char]] = List(List(0), List(1))
val of2 = gray(2)    //> of2  : List[List[Char]] = List(List(0, 0), List(1, 0), List(0, 1), List(1, 1))
...
```

Comment: Ok but that's also use the recursion way. Anyway you got my +1 =)

Answer (score 1):

that should do the trick?

```
object GrayTest {

  def gray(i:Int):List[String] =
  {
    if (i == 0 ) List("")
    else {
      val l = gray(i-1)
      l.map("0" + _) ::: l.reverse.map("1"+_)
    }
  }

  def main(arg:Array[String]) =
  {
    println(gray(3))
  }

}
```

Comment: I already build this function. And why do you reverse the list ? I think you misunderstood my question.

Comment: from wikipedia: The binary-reflected Gray code list for n bits can be generated recursively from the list for n−1 bits by reflecting the list (i.e. listing the entries in reverse order), concatenating the original list with the reversed list, prefixing the entries in the original list with a binary 0, and then prefixing the entries in the reflected list with a binary 1

Comment: Ok well that's the definition, but that's definitely not answer my question.